# Forms Authentication Between IIS6 and IIS7 Servers

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-6, iis-7.5

I have two web servers on the same subnet, one a Windows Server 2003 with IIS6 and the other a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7 (might be 7.5 I suppose).

I want to provide a single sign on between both websites.  Both are ASP.NET 2.0 hosted sites and the machine keys match on both machines in the web.config file.  Also, my authentication attributes also match.

When I log into the first server (IIS6) and try to connect to a page on the second server (IIS7) using an IFrame, the IFrame page is being redirected to the login page.

I have verified that the forms authentication cookie is being created and the "domain" setting are the same in both web.config files.

I have the application pool on the IIS7 server running under "classic" mode, but that has made no difference.

Any ideas?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the machine key (used to encrypt the forms authentication token) is the same on both machines:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/09/16/forms-authentication-fails-after-installing-iis-7-5.aspx

Comment: Thanks Chris, but as per my original post "**Both are ASP.NET 2.0 hosted sites and the machine keys match on both machines in the web.config file. Also, my authentication attributes also match.**"

The machine keys are identical.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Apologies, I missed that line.